# New customer account link not automatically highlighted

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, customer-account

I'm trying to figure out why Magento is not highlighting my new customer account link when I access the corresponding page. Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
      </default>
    <customer_account translate="label">
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink"><name>Mes parrainages</name><path>mesparrainages/index/index/</path><label>Mes parrainages</label></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
      <mesparrainagesrouter_index_index>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
           <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
                <block type="parrainage/mesparrainagesblock" name="bloc_mesparrainages" as="bloc_mesparrainages" template="parrainage/mesparrainages.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </mesparrainagesrouter_index_index>
</layout>
```

I'm using CE 1.9, maybe they changed the way it works.. Somebody have an idea please ?

Edit: Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Motion4Ever_Parrainage>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Motion4Ever_Parrainage>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
      <routers>
          <mesparrainagesrouter>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                  <module>Motion4Ever_Parrainage</module>
                  <frontName>mesparrainages</frontName>
              </args>
          </mesparrainagesrouter>
      </routers>
      <layout>
          <updates>
              <parrainage>
                  <file>parrainage/layout.xml</file>
              </parrainage>
          </updates>
      </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <blocks>
       <parrainage>
            <class>Motion4Ever_Parrainage_Block</class>
       </parrainage>
    </blocks>
    <template>
        <email>
            <email_parrainage module="parrainage">
                <label>Email parrainage</label>
                <file>email_parrainage.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </email_parrainage>
        </email>
    </template>
    <helpers>
      <parrainage>
        <class>Motion4Ever_Parrainage_Helper</class>
      </parrainage>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <parrainage>
        <class>Motion4Ever_Parrainage_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>parrainage_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </parrainage>
      <parrainage_mysql4>
        <class>Motion4Ever_Parrainage_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>        
              <filleul>
                <table>filleul</table>
              </filleul>
        </entities>
      </parrainage_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <parrainage_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Motion4Ever_Parrainage</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </parrainage_setup>
      <parrainage_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </parrainage_write>
      <parrainage_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </parrainage_read>
      <customerattribute1407966696_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Motion4Ever_Parrainage</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1407966696_setup>
      <customerattribute1407966696_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1407966696_write>
      <customerattribute1407966696_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1407966696_read>
    </resources>
    <events>
      <customer_register_success> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <customer_register_success_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>parrainage/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>registerCustomerObserve</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </customer_register_success_handler>
        </observers>
      </customer_register_success>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Here is my template :

```
<div class="dashboard">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Mes parrainages'); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('mesparrainages/index/addfilleul/'); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="form-validate" class="scaffold-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="parrain_customer_id" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId(); ?>">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend">Ajouter un filleul</h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
                <label for="email" class="required">Adresse email</label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="email" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="email_filleul" id="email" title="Adresse email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email">
                    <button type="submit" title="Enregistrer" class="button"><span><span>Ajouter filleul</span></span></button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
    <table class="data-table">
        <col />
        <col width="160" />
        <col width="120" />
        <col width="60" />
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Email du filleul') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Statut') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Code promo') ?></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $filleuls = $this->getFilleuls(); 
            if($filleuls){ ?>
                <tbody id="filleuls">
                <?php foreach($filleuls as $filleul): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $filleul->getEmailFilleul(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->getStatut($filleul); ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><button id="resend" data-email="<?php echo $filleul->getEmailFilleul(); ?>" type="submit" title="Renvoyer" class="button"><span><span>Renvoyez l'email</span></span></button></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan = "4">Vous n'avez pas encore de filleuls !</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#resend').on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).text()=="Renvoyez l'email"){
            var email = $(this).data("email");
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('mesparrainages/index/sendemail/'); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: { email : email },
                context: this,
                success:function(){
                    $(this).text("Email envoyé !");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#form-validate").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $(this).find('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('mesparrainages/index/addfilleul/'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            context: this,
            success:function(data){
                $("#filleuls").prepend("<tr><td>"+email+"</td><td>Pas encore inscrit</td><td>Aucun</td><td><button id='resend' type='submit' title='Renvoyer' class='button'><span><span>Email envoyé !</span></span></button></td></tr>");
                $(this).find('#email').val(null);
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: provide template.phtml file and config.xml file of your module

Comment: @programmer_rkt I edited the first post ;)

Comment: show your full config.xml and template.phtml

Comment: @programmer_rkt okey ;) sorry for that but i'm french, and i'm too tired to change all the names, i just did not sleep at all tonight

Comment: `my.account.wrapper` is this block is already existing one ?

Comment: in base/default/layout/customer.xml

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your block definition is wrong here

```
<block type="modulename/blockname" name="block_name" template="template.phtml" />
```

As per your module configuration it should look like

```
<block type="parrainage/blockname" name="block_name" as="block_name" template="template.phtml" />
```

since `parrainage` is the alias for your module's block. But in order to ensure this block render its content, you may also need to look on this

**1. You should have block defined in backend**

Location : `app/code/local/Motion4Ever/Parrainage/Block/Blockname.php`

```
<?php
class Motion4Ever_Parrainage_Block_Blockname extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

}
```

Without defining this block class, Magento would not understand which block that you are referencing in layout file

**2. You need to ensure the parent block is defined before referencing the block.**

In this case, this step won't be necessary. Since it is defined in `customer.xml`

Comment: This isn't solving my problem.. My block is correctly defined, since it's actually working, only the left hand side highlighting of the menu is not ;) I'm adding my proper layout.xml file